# Convert multi-page tiff file to multiple tiff pages

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I am trying convert single multi-tiff file into multiple single page tiff files with small tiff size and with good quality in c# Console Application.

I am not finding any ghost-script/Post script or any third part library command line to make it happen.

I have used below code which converts it but the file size is huge.I want color page tiff with good quality.

```
string strMultiTiffFile = @"D:\\ba3acf3e-cf9f-49ee-aa7b-b4061eca5ee0.tif";
            Image image = Image.FromFile(strMultiTiffFile);
            Guid guid = image.FrameDimensionsList[0];

            FrameDimension frameDimension = new FrameDimension(guid);
            int noofPages = image.GetFrameCount(frameDimension);
            ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = null;
            imageCodecInfo = getImageCodeInfo("image/tiff");

            string strOutPutDirectories = @"D:\ConvertTo";

            foreach (Guid _guid in image.FrameDimensionsList)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < noofPages; i++)
                {
                    FrameDimension currentframe = new FrameDimension(_guid);
                    image.SelectActiveFrame(currentframe, i);
                    image.Save(Path.Combine(strOutPutDirectories, i + ".tiff"), imageCodecInfo, null);
                }
            }
```

Any other library will also be helpful. Need some code/guide.

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't read TIFF files, so it isn't going to help you with this. PostScript interpreters can't read TIFF files (because they aren't PostScript) though you can write a PostScript program to do so. I can't think why you would bother though. I'd have thought ImageMagick would be more the thing.

Comment: @kenS Do you have any example of ImageMagick in c# for Multi tiff ti single page tiff?.I am not finding any example on ImageMagick

Comment: Nope, I'm a PostScript developer working with/on Ghostscript. But I'd have thought any image editing/manipulating tool would be much better placed to deal with TIFF files than Ghostscript/PostScript. While its possible to wirte a TIFF reader using PostScript (there are links to a version I wrote years ago scattered around SO) it would be a lot easier to use a more appropriate programming language from scratch.